# Paragraph ended before \TP@textblock was complete

Tags: tables

I have a question. Where is the problem?? the error appears when i use in the second tabular \begin{textblock*}. Help me, please

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=hang,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRule{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  blabla}} 
\HRule{1pt}\\ [0.6cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} Luca \\ \textbf{Cognome:} blabla \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} blablabla} 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} 21-22}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRule{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
blabla
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{blablabla \mbox{alla} matricola}

blablabla; \\

\hspace{12pt}\textbf{Numero Matricola: blabla}
\begin{enumerate}
 
    \item blabla
    \item blabla

$ blablabla $ \\



\item blablabla

\begin{textblock*}{150pt}(150pt, 30pt)
\begin{tabular}{r|c}
    
        42280&0 \\
        21140&0 \\
        10570&0 \\
        5285&1 \\
        2642&0 \\
        1321&1 \\
        660&0 \\
        330& 0 \\
        165&1 \\
        82&0 \\
        41&1 \\
        20&0 \\
        10&0 \\
        5&1 \\
        2&0 \\
        1&1 \\
        0& / \\
    
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}
    \caption{blablabla}
    \label{tab: Fun} 
\end{table}
\end{textblock*}


\begin{textblock*}{180pt}(220pt,20pt)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, -9) {};
    \node (B) at (0, 0) {};
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}
\newpage

Letto dal basso verso l'alto, come indica la freccia nella Tabella (\ref{tab: Fun}), il \mbox{risultato} è il seguente: \\

\hspace{4cm} $blablabla$ \\

\item blablabla :

\end{enumerate}

\begin{textblock*}{100pt}{180pt,50pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c||c } 
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x, y, z, w)$ \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{textblock*}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\begin{textblock*}{100pt}{180pt,50pt}` should be `\begin{textblock*}{100pt}(180pt,50pt)`.

Comment: I don't believe it, I'm blind ahaha thank u so much